# Get Beautfiulsoup div class content

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup, findall

i'm working on beautifulsoup. I want to access the text in div. My code is below.

```
attack = atackersoup.findAll("div", {"class":"col-12 description"})
```

and my output is below

```
<div class="col-12 description">
                A denial of service vulnerability was identified that exists in Apache SpamAssassin before 3.4.2.
            </div>
```

I just want the text. Do not show div tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `text` from the tag, use this:

```
print(attack.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
A denial of service vulnerability was identified that exists in Apache SpamAssassin before 3.4.2.
```

Here is the full code:

```
html = """
<div class="col-12 description">
                A denial of service vulnerability was identified that exists in Apache SpamAssassin before 3.4.2.
            </div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "col-12 description")

print(div.text.strip())
```

Since you have a list of elements, you should loop thru the elements and print the text, like:

```
for div in attack:
    print(div.text.strip())
```

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? I tried find_all() and find() but didn't work

Comment: Oh...It is bcs u have used find_all. Just loop thru the elements and print the text.